# Using variable in SELECT query inside IN comparison

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, variables

Here is a simple example:

Why does this work:

```
DECLARE @v as varchar(75)
SET @v = 'xxx-xxxx'
SELECT * FROM tbl_skus WHERE SKU = @v
```

But this does not work:

```
DECLARE @v as varchar(75)
SET @v = 'xxx-xxxx,yyy-yyyy'
SELECT * FROM tbl_skus WHERE SKU IN ( @v )
```

Both SKUs 'xxx-xxxx' and 'yyy-yyyy' are in the table. The first query pulls 1 result, and the second pulls 0 results; no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your query is looking for the literal `'xxx-xxxx,yyy-yyyy'`, it means that it's just one string, with a comma in it, not 2 strings separated by a comma.
Your query translates to:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_skus WHERE SKU IN ('xxx-xxxx,yyy-yyyy')
```

And for it to work as you want, it shoul be:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_skus WHERE SKU IN ('xxx-xxxx','yyy-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign two values to a single variable. You will have to do something like this:

DECLARE @v as varchar(75)
DECLARE @a as varchar(75)

SET @v = 'xxx-xxxx'
SET @a = 'yyy-yyyy'

SELECT * FROM tbl_skus
WHERE SKU IN (@v, @a)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a cursor like this (for example):

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT Table_Training_Detalis.DateExpires,Table_Training_Detalis.Worker_ID
FROM   Table_Courses 
OPEN @MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
INTO @ColExpir,@ColWorkid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
update Table_Workers set WHIMIS= @ColExpir where Worker_ID=@ColWorkid

FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
INTO @ColExpir,@ColWorkid
END
CLOSE @MyCursor
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor
```